# NE555 - astable flashing alternative LED circuit

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, oscillator, 555, astable

NE 555 help - astable alternate flashing LED circuit

"In the circuit, the LED1 lights when the output pin has a HIGH state and LED2 lights when the output is in a LOW state." - I couldn't understand this statement in connection with the diagram:

[image]

Here I see a normal LED1 connected to output terminal 3 and to ground and I can understand as how Vcc / high output will appear and then the LED will turn on ,

What I can't understand is how LED2 turns on when output is low: we know LED2 is connected to Vcc and the negative terminal to output 3, when current flows through it and turns it on, the output at 3 should be low to have a voltage difference and hence led 2 turns on.

But then when current flows through LED2 - after flowing through 2, where will it travel, as pin 3 is the dead end as the output there is low, can current flow inside the push-pull amplifier (which inverts the output from flip-flop ) and then flow to ground via discharge transistor or am I missing something?

Comment: I think that they were mistaken. LED 1 should be on when the output is low, and LED 2 should be on when the output is high.

Comment: Is it actually "the LED2 lights when the output pin has a HIGH state and LED1 lights when the output is in a LOW state." ??

Comment: @AdityaChavan interchange the led 1 and led 2 tags on diagram , sorry

Comment: @Parker what i cant understand is what i have asked , thanks for spotting the glitch

Comment: Murphy's Law. If anything  can be inverted... it will be.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 i didnt understand ?

Comment: You actually had the right idea, the current flows from the discharge transistor of the push pull amplifier to ground.

Comment: To avoid Murphy's Law, like carpenters, measure 3 times cut once.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law  The author made a "brain fart"

Comment: As an aside for this circuit, it only works with low currents.  Once you want to make bright LEDs, the lower resistor values will allow current to always flow and the two LEDs will always be on.  Transistors to the rescue!

Comment: @Aaron could u elaborate on the second part of your comment please - transistors to the rescue and when u said that lower resistor values will allow current to always flow .

Comment: If you want to pulse \$100mA\$ (or more), through some white LEDs, then you have \$9V-2*3V=3V\$ and \$3V/100mA=30Ω\$. So do you think that 9V can forward bias two LEDs in series with two 30Ω resistors? Answer=yes it can.

Comment: The solution is to use an NPN and a PNP transistor with their bases connected to pin 3 through resistors.  Then they turn different LEDs on in an alternating fashion, and you can even do larger strings of LEDs and use a seperate supply to do 1W or higher LEDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit redrawn is circuit 1 and there are two possible states circuit 2 and circuit 3.

Circuit 2 is the High state of the 555 timer. In this state the voltage across the top led is 0 (9V on anode and 9V on cathode) which means no current flows and the led is off. Meanwhile the bottom led is on because there is a positive voltage across its terminals (9V on anode and 0V on cathode.). This means that current flows from the 555 through the diode to the ground.

Circuit 3 is the Low state of the 555 timer. This state is the opposite of the previous. Now there is a voltage drop across the top diode and no drop across the bottom. This means that the top is on and the bottom is off. The current flows from the 9V source through the top led and into the 555.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQl6m0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The internal circuitry of the 555 output pin is essentially this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN1xnN.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Think of this from the LEDs POV, when the output is high, LED1 has a a potential difference of 0 between its 2 pins and LED2 has a potential difference of 9V, and vice versa for when the output is LOW, the Potential difference for LED1 is 9V and for LED2 is 0V.
How this works internally is that for making the output low, ne555 connects its output to ground, so the current flow into the IC at that point

Comment: I've ignored the resistor voltage drop to simplify the analogy, FYI

Comment: but what would the current flow look like ,  i understand there is a voltage difference , when the top LED in diagram has potential difference , the current should flow somewhere right ???

Comment: It would flow into the IC, if you see the internal schematics of any GPIO on any controller, the mechanism is this: to make the output high, a switch connects the output pin to VCC, to make the output pin LOW, a switch connects the output to GND. So the current flows into the IC at that point.

Comment: so u mean to say that when there is voltage difference between Vcc and pin 3 between the top LED  , the current flows through led and then inside through pin 3 , passing the push pull amplifier and then to the discharge and then to ground ??

Comment: If you see the internal schematics of a ne555, you see a output driver which is a not gate. Now look up how not gates are implemented in VLSI, it consists of a 2 transistors, if you activate the bottom one, the output is grounded. Current flows through this transistor to GND.

Comment: oh wow , how wonderful this is , so basically current flows in and is grounded from the transistor inside the  not gate arrangement of the output driver ?

Comment: Correct, this is standard for most 2 state-output drivers, and is a clever way to ensure the current always gets a path to flow from.

Comment: thank you sir for helping me out , could i please also get recommendations to learn this type of information about state outputs , ICS , the VLSI structures and working and how high/low logic  and voltage and current flow are attributed in ICs ? this was a small doubt but i learnt a lot from it .

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if answer helped. If you need recommendations, there are excellent resources available on Youtube and the internet, there are courses by NPTEL or IIT which are available freely, you may also benefit from reading about the VLSI structures of all the basic gates (AND, OR, etc) as a good starting point. If the internet is not your thing, there will be many VLSI books in your local library as well. It doesn't matter who the author is, pick one and start reading!